# How to interpret this Ramda signature?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js, hindley-milner

Could someone explain how to understand this notation:

```
((a, b) → a) → a → [b] → a
```

See: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce

Comment: See also the [description](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures) on Ramda's wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
((a, b) → a) → a → [b] → a
^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^   ^^^   ^
1              2   3     4
```

This is a function that takes three arguments (1) (2) (3) and returns a value of type `a` (4):

1. The 1st arg is a function that takes two arguments (maybe of the same type) and returns a value of the same type as the first argument.
2. The 2nd argument is a value of type `a`
3. The 3rd argument is a list of values of type `b`

```js
reduce( (acc, x) => acc + x.length,    0,   ["foo", "bar", "baz"]); //=> 9
//       ^^^  ^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^
//       a    b     a                  a    [b]                          a
//     ((a -> b) -> a             ) -> a -> [b]                       -> a
```

In this case `a` stands for the `number` type and `b` stands for the `string` type.

Comment: Very nice, concise answer!  I'd love to have [one more line](http://fourwindssoft.com/link/16) that reintroduced the parentheses.

Comment: @customcommander that was the best explanation I've ever seen. Could you please tell me how this signature should be treated  ((acc, x) → (acc, y)) → acc → [x] → (acc, [y]). It takes three arguments and returns a tuple. I have trouble understanding the left side: ((acc, x) → (acc, y)) - it takes a function with two arguments that returns what? Another function?

Answer (score 3):

I believe its Hindley-Milner notation: https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch7.html